# How extensible is Google Moderator?

Tags: iframe, reddit, vote-up-buttons, google-moderator

I am trying to integrate vote-up-buttons similar as in [Reddit](http://code.reddit.com/wiki/RedditStartToFinish) to [Google Moderator](http://moderator.appspot.com/).

However, Google Moderator does not give me Shell access. This suggests me that the only way is to use Vote-up-buttons from an external server set by iframes.

I would like to know

1. How can you can assign Iframe_A to a question in Google Moderator?
2. How can you can show an iframe in Google moderator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There used to be a [Google Moderator API](http://code.google.com/apis/moderator/v1/getting_started.html) but it has now been deprecated.